# Upgrade to .net 6

Tags: version, upgrade

I wonder if you have any plan to upgrade the current .net 5 to .net 6 for your github. (https://github.com/ITfoxtec/ITfoxtec.Identity.BlazorWebAssembly.OpenidConnect).  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, I just have not had time to look at it yet.

---

UPDATE: Support for .NET 6.0 has been added in version 1.6.2.

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is pretty simple  you just have to change you project frame work to .net 6 and just push it to git.

as you see this is .net 5
https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWmKc.png

change to .net 6
and push the code :)